# NSObject retainCount not showing the proper value

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, retaincount

I am having the property as follows

```
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSArray *dataArray;
```

I am trying to display the retainCount as follows

```
- (void)viewDidLoad    
{        
         [super viewDidLoad];
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

          self.dataArray=[NSArray new];

         NSLog(@"Retain Count1 %d",[dataArray retainCount]);

        [dataArray release];

        NSLog(@"Retain Count2 %d",[dataArray retainCount]);        
}
```

As per as my understanding **Retain Count1** and **Retain Count2** should be **1** and **0** resp.

But I am getting the strange values **22**  and **21** resp  and when I run again sometimes the

retain count will be again  incremented by **1** . Any help is greatly appreciated .

Comment: It is not recommended to use retainCount for any reason. You will "never" get the expected values.

Comment: @Raj why you rolled back my edit ? your original is less understandable

Comment: Also note that with ARC (you are using `strong` so I assume you are compiling with ARC), `retainCount` shouldn't be even accessible.

Comment: @giorashc: Sorry it was by mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not ever use `retainCount` for tracking object's references 
as the object might be retained internally without you knowing it causing the `retainCount` to show what you think is an incorrect result.

This [site](http://whentouseretaincount.com/) will help you further :)